# Why I have to add the energy of water to the equation?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, temperature

The question was, "It's given that the specific heat capacity of water and coffee are 4200 and 4800 respectively. Specific latent heat of fusion of ice is 3.34 x 10^5. What is the final temperature of the mixture if 100g of ice at 0 Degree Celsius is added to 150g of coffee at 60 Degree Celsius?" Although my teacher already gave the equation: 0.15(4800)(60-T) = (3.34 x 10^5)(0.1) + (0.1)(4200)(T-0). But I still don't understand why we have to add (0.1)(4200)(T-0) into the equation. Is it because the ice will melt into the water? If so, I hope someone can specific it. If not, then I hope someone can give me an answer. Thanks if anyone will be able to answer it!

Comment: Hi and welcome to physics SE. Please, use laTex notation for formulae. It's about writing them in between of dollar symbols, and laTex commands inside, like this `$v^2=\frac{GM}{r}$` . See here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: It would be nice if you would declare the units that you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it because the ice will melt into the water?

Yes.

In the equation the ice and coffee water are treated as two separate components of the mixture.

The heat (latent heat of fusion) added to the ice at constant temperature results in a phase change to water. Then additional heat is added to the water to increase its temperature from 0 to the final temperature T of the mixture. See the left figure below.

The coffee water component of the mixture, on the other hand, is cooled from its initial temperature to the same final temperature as the ice water without undergoing any phase change. See the right figure below.

For conservation of energy, the heat extracted from the coffee water equals the heat absorbed by the ice and ice water.

Hope this helps.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the ice melts to become water, which must then be heated.

Answer (score 0):

There are two complications not mentioned in the accepted and correct answer.

1. The equation in the body of the OP does not account for the possibility of energy being absorbed/emitted when the melted pure water mixes with and dilutes the coffee.  It's as if the piece of ice had been wrapped in plastic film before being dropped into the hot coffee, so that the ice exchanged heat energy with the hot coffee, but did not mix.  In this case the energy is probably insignificant.  But try using this technique to find the result of mixing cold sulfuric acid and hot water!
2. The given equation is faulty in another way.  If the piece of ice were larger, or the coffee cooler or less massive, solving the equation could result in a negative value for T!  You would need to use a different equation;  one in which an unknown fraction of the ice melts to water at 0 degrees and cools all the coffee to 0 degrees Celsius.